# What parameters are useful for an Albers equal area projection map of the world

Tags: proj

I have a data set which contains global points.  I would like to convert from long/lat to Albers equal area.  However, the http://spatialreference.org proj4 world parameter values are actually for the USA.

Albers equal area might not be the best, both that is what I need to do.

Thanks!

Comment: @whuber: The wikipedia article shows a map of the world. Perhaps he wants just that?

Comment: @Andre I think you're right; I'll withdraw my comment.  Thanks.  For the record, the [Wikipedia article on the Albers projection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Albers_projection) contains an illustration of a world map (and in the caption provides the necessary parameters, although these are not the only ones possible).

Answer (score 1):

According to O.S. Adams's [General Theory of Equivalent Projections (1945)](ftp://ftp.library.noaa.gov/docs.lib/htdocs/rescue/cgs_specpubs/QB275U35no2361945.pdf) (p.37, of the article not the PDF):

> Besides the representation of the two hemispheres just described, it is sometimes
>   desired to represent the whole world on one map. If it is desired to have an equal-area
>   map of this kind, it would be necessary to use a conic projection with minimum
>   deformations between the north pole and 50º south latitude. The deformation beyond
>   the parallel of 50º south would not be troublesome as no land of importance lies beyond
>   that point, since only a tip of South America extends further south. The north pole
>   should be taken as the center and the separation should be made at 170º west longitude
>   which passes through Bering Strait and does not meet any land area. This projection
>   corresponds to *m*=0.432; it does not produce any deformation along the parallel of
>   18º25' south; at the north pole, a singular point of the projection, 2δ amounts to
>   118º26'. The greatest value of 2δ besides this point is 58º43'; of *a*², 1.710 and of *a*², 2.924.

My interpretation of that (someone please correct me if I'm wrong):

- longitude of origin = 10º E
- first standard parallel = 90º N
- second standard parallel = 18º25' S

Answer (score 1):

To convert from long/lat to Albers equal area, from [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Albers_projection) Wikipedia article about the Albers projection:

> Coordinates from a spherical datum can be transformed into Albers equal-area conic projection coordinates with the following formulas, where λ is the longitude, λ0 the reference longitude, φ the latitude, φ0 the reference latitude and φ1 and φ2 the standard parallels:
>
> [image]